# Silverlight Control Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, user-controls, mvvm

I'm fairly new to Silverlight, and am using an MVVM architecture.

I have created a popup which contains a dropdown combobox which contains list objects.

A button below indicates "Add List Item", thus when a list object is selected from the above combobox, and whenver the button is clicked, I want to display a row with the following:

---- reusable control ----

a delete button, a dropdown combobox of all child list items to the top combobox, and a text field, where I can make one association.

---- reusable control ----

So my issue is, how to create a reusable control to appear each time I click the button, and when viewing, showing all items in the list.

If someone has some examples of this, that would be great.

Thanks.